# Dockerfile vs docker-compile.yml for certain parameters

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm somewhat confused of the relationship between Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.  I understand Dockerfile is for creating the image and compose is for running it.  But options like expose and command I'm not sure what difference it makes where I put them.

In my Dockerfile I can have:

```
EXPOSE 8001

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8001"]
```

and I can leave it out in my docker-compose.yml and it works fine, other services on the network can see it.  I know the host wont see it since I didn't define ports but that's okay.  But I often see people define the expose and command in the docker-compose.yml file.  What is the difference?  Should I define the expose/ports and command in both places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXPOSE` is mostly documentation.  In the unusual event you `docker run -P`, Docker will publish all exposed ports on the host, and pick its own ports for the host ports; this won't have port conflicts, but you need to `docker inspect` the container to find the host port, and that's kind of a hassle.

`CMD` in a Dockerfile provides a default for the `command:` in `docker-compose.yml` and also the last half of the `docker run` command.  If you can put some default in the Dockerfile that's better (the thing you've quoted for instance is very reasonable).  But it's helpful if you can

```
# Run the server
docker run -p8001:8001 myimage

# ...well, that didn't work, why not?
docker run --rm -it myimage /bin/sh
```

which works better if the image knows its own default `CMD`.

(I'd recommend avoiding `ENTRYPOINT` unless you know what it's for; a typical setup would be pointing it at a shell script does some setup work and then ends in `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`.)